# vuejs - how to set tag parameters based on a condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm showing a [v-tippy](https://kabbouchi.github.io/vue-tippy/4.0/getting-started.html) this way:

```
<label v-tippy content="My content text">
```

It is working fine, but I need now to show it based on a condition `show_tip == true`.

How can I do that?

Comment: could you give a link of that directive lib

Comment: here it is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tippy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case use as component not as directive in order to make the conditional rendering :

```
<tippy v-if="show_tip" content=""My content text" >
       <label slot="trigger" >Label text</label>
</tippy>
```

or

```
 <tippy :visible="show_tip" content=""My content text" >
       <label slot="trigger" >Label text</label>
</tippy>
```

Comment: it shows this error: `Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. found in ---> <Tippy>`

Comment: I guess so cause it's working on another approach.
I've imported the .min.js file and mounted the component `Vue.component("tippy", VueTippy);`

Comment: try to import it in your component using `import { tippy } from "vue-tippy";` then add it to components option